# Android studio: cannot add new ui elements

Tags: android, android-studio

I've recently had to add some radio buttons in a view in an app. 
However, I can't actually compile since when compiling I get the following error: `error: cannot find symbol variable CR` where CR is the id of the new UI element. However, it recognizes previously created UI elements without an issue (in the same layout, of course).

```
        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.02">

                <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/CR"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Example text" />
        </RadioGroup>
```

This xml leads to CR not being found.

```
  <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Note"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="@string/note"
            android:textColor="@color/borderColor" />
```

Just as a comparison, I can find this view without any issues.
In order, here are the `findViewById()` calls for both ids:

`RadioButton cardLeft = findViewById(R.id.CR); //leads to symbol not found`

`final EditText NoteField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Note); //works perfectly`.

I also noticed that the id doesn't appear in any way in R.

Here is what I did to try to solve the problem:

`Clean Project-->Rebuild`

`Invalidate Caches and restart`

`Invalidate Caches-->clean project-->Restart`

`Deleted R`

`Checked that android.R wasn't being imported`

`Recreated the project and imported the code from git (and only the code, no generated files of course)`

`Tried changing IDs, just in case, to no avail.`

`Changed Settings-->Data Binding to "Reference code generated by the compiler" instead of "Reference code generated by Android Studio"`

Clearly, any modification to the code or settings followed with cache invalidation and a project clean, just in case.
Further testing showed that I can't add new UI items at all, since they don't get added to R.

Autocomplete shows the new Ids to have a negative values instead of an address.

So, since I've completely run out of ideas, is there anything I missed/more unknown solutions for this problem?

Comment: you did not give id to RadioGroup. it belongs to that group. you may try to find eg: rg.findViewById(R.id.CR);

Comment: In the posted code example I didn't, right. However, when testing I tried giving it an id and finding it, and I still couldn't. So I couldn't do what you are suggesting.

I just tried it again, and yeah, same:
`RadioGroup group = findViewById(R.id.Group);` leads to: "Error, cannot find symbol variable Group" even after a project clean, invalidate caches and restart.

Comment: Sometimes simply closing the project and reopening it (from the Android Studio main dialog) fixes goof behavior with R.

Comment: Yes, I also tried that and forgot to add it. Also, I think it would have been covered in "starting a new project and importing from github"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to solve this was to declare the ids in a custom xml file, and then use `android:id="@id/CR"` instead of `android:id="@+id/CR`.

It is a workaround, though, and it didn't solve the real issue, so I'm still open for suggestions, just in case.